# Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, with IntelliJ Idea, Maven and JDK 19

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javafx

The problem is when i try to run my main class i get the error from above.
I'm using Intellij IDEA

Added dependencies and plugin in pom.xml
Ran mvn clean install, also mvn clean javafx:run
But I can't run my main class

Here is what i added to pom

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
  <version>19</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
  <version>19</version>
</dependency>
```

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.8</version>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>App</mainClass>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 5):

## *File > New Project > Generators > JavaFX*

I suggest starting with a new project created by [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) explicitly aimed at [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX).

Use the ***JavaFX* option in the *Generators* list**, in the [*New Project* wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html).

[image: screenshot of New Project wizard, using JavaFX option]

You will get a full working example app, that runs successfully.

The code is [modularized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) with a `module-info.java` file.

[image: screenshot of working JavaFX app with a "Hello!" button in middle of a small window]

The example app uses [FXML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FXML). If you wish, you can easily delete that. You can use only Java coding without any FXML markup coding — your choice. If you opt out of FXML, delete the dependency for `javafx-fxml` from your POM.

The [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model) looks like the following. Notice the inclusion of [OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/) dependencies.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>fxdemo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>fxdemo</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.9.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>19</source>
                    <target>19</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>work.basil.example.fxdemo/work.basil.example.fxdemo.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

By the way, you can replace the property `<junit.version>5.9.1</junit.version>` and the pair of JUnit dependencies with [this simpler single “Aggregator” dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter/5.9.1):

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoFX</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demoFX</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>19</source>
                    <target>19</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>work.basil.example.demofx/work.basil.example.demofx.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I hope this question doesn’t get closed, then as all the future duplicates come in that use Idea and JavaFX, I can just close them as a duplicate of this answer :-)