# JavaFX: Cannot change default JavaFX platform

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, sdk, platform

I am using Netbeans IDE 17. I have a problem with setting a different JavaFX platform version. Therefore I cannot create new JavaFx project.

Tools/Java Platforms:

[image: Add Platform]

When creating a new JavaFX project I tried multiple times to add new platforms, but I cannot choose them in the combobox:

[image: New Project]

Comment: I think the new JavaFX platform stuff in NetBeans is obsolete and broken.  Instead follow the getting started instructions for NetBeans at openjfx.io.

Comment: If you have been stuck for a long time, try a different approach.  To quickly get started, I advise downloading idea and using the [new JavaFX project wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74764217/error-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing-with-intellij-idea-maven-and-jdk/74764297#74764297).

Comment: you can make a maven javafx project in netbeans  [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74924150/7587451)

Comment: [_"Don't try to create a JavaFX project."_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73611827/230513)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The good news is that your issue is fairly easy to fix. The bad news is that you are going to encounter another problem once that is resolved, for which there is no easy fix.

First, note from your screen shot that you are invited to provide a "**JavaFX** Platform" rather than just a "**Java** Platform". That is, you need to provide a JDK which includes the JavaFX modules, and presumably your selection of *JDK 20 (Default)* is not valid.

[Azul Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azul_Systems) and [BellSoft](https://bell-sw.com/) are two [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) vendors offering editions that bundle the necessary JavaFX ([OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/)) libraries. Here is a screen shot of the Azul site, https://www.azul.com/downloads/?package=jdk#zulu

[image: Azul Download]

Be sure to specify *JDK FX* for the **Java Package**. I downloaded the zip (rather than the msi) and after unzipping had a top level directory named **zulu19.32.15-ca-fx-jdk19.0.2-win_x64**. Use **Tools > Java Platforms > Add Platform...** to create a new Java platform, specifying that directory. I named my new platform **Java193215Azul**:

[image: Add Platform]

Now you should be able to avoid the problem shown in your screen shot. Navigate to **File > New Project... > Java with Ant > JavaFX > JavaFX Application**, and click **Next >**. On the **New JavaFX Application** screen in the **JavaFX Platform** field select the Azul SDK you just downloaded and added as a Java platform:

[image: NetBeans Wizard]

There should be no error now, and you can click **Finish** to generate your project.

That resolves your issue, but it's important to note that when you build the JavaFX application generated by the NetBeans wizard you will get an unrelated build error:

[image: Build error]

A bug report for that issue was raised almost a year ago, but has not been resolved. See the NetBeans Bug [Build Failed #3996](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/3996):

> When I build javafx app this error appear "Unable to create javax
> script engine for JavaScript in javafx".

To avoid this issue there are alternative approaches for JavaFX development which may or may not suit you:

- Create a [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) project rather than an [Ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) project in NetBeans.
- Use an alternative IDE, such as [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) offering a JavaFX template for new projects. See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74764297/642706) for details.
- Regress to a much earlier version of NetBeans (12.0 or earlier) and use [JDK 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_8).

One final point: although you can't build a JavaFX project generated by the wizard when using Ant, it is still possible to run the file containing the **main()** method that was generated by the wizard, using **Run > Run File**. Here's a screen shot showing that file being run after I made a couple of cosmetic changes in the code:

[image: Run File]

Of course that approach has limited value, but I mention it for completeness.