# Netbeans JavaFX SDK installation configuration problem?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, netbeans

I use the latest release version of zulu that includes the JavaFX SDK and the hairstyle version of Netbeans 18 on my Mac. With the default configuration, Netbeans also recognizes JDK 20, but when I open the configuration panel of the JavaFX tab that configures Java, I encounter the following problems ,How to solve this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwikh.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzDri.png)

how to solve this problem

Comment: More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75962754/230513). Also consider [openjfx](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).