# JavaFX runtime components are missing

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, javafx

In both NetBeans and IntelliJ Idea, when I use javaFX, I get Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
In intelliJ I have javaFX 2 installed, in netbeans I have connected all jar files. How to solve this?

I downloaded VS Code, changed the settings in launch.json there, but everything remains the same. for the solution in netbeans I reinstalled javafx and jdk, doesn't help. What to do with this?

Comment: "_I have javaFX 2 installed_" -- Are you sure you have version **2** installed? That's a very old, obsolete version. Assuming that isn't a typo, I recommend upgrading to at least the latest 17.0.x LTS version or preferably the latest 21.0.x LTS version.

Comment: Try following the instructions at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ for your chosen IDE and build tool. If you still can't get any project working, please update your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ohhhh. I just created a simple maven archetype project and that's it, I didn't even have to change anything in the code. Well, I don't want to understand intelliJ and VSC, I'm just moving from intellij to netbeans, and I downloaded VSC just to solve this problem.Thanks!

Comment: In Netbeans you can use maven like so [create javafx application using netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74923410/how-do-i-create-a-javafx-application-using-netbeans-ide-and-java-19-0-1/74924150#74924150)

Comment: If you use JDK 17: Download this repo, extract it, and run it with IntelliJ: https://github.com/davidweber411/javafx-JavaFxAppMavenNonModular