# JavaFX not running error Module javafx.controls not found

Tags: javafx

after following the proccedure under Non-Moduler from IDE and running the programe, i am getting the error-

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found

after installing JavaFX I was expecting the programe to rum without error however, I got-
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found

Comment: Which IDE?  Which instructions?  Anyway, your issue is that you have not set the VM options correctly in the IDE, so the relevant JavaFX modules cannot be found (they are not on the module path).  The documentation at openjfx.io runs through how to do this for various IDEs, or if it is Idea, use the [new JavaFX project wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74764297/1155209).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I was trying to set up JavaFX in my eclipse IDE. On my run configuration, I specified the VM path as provided documentation at openjfx.io. I changed the path under argument to "--module-path "C:\Java\javafx-sdk-19\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml" I still got the error JavaFX not running error Module javafx.controls not found. But I figured out the problem was I did not specify the path in the Preference under JavaFX / JavaFX11+SDK  to  C:\Java\javafx-sdk-19\lib

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to set up JavaFX in my eclipse IDE. On my run configuration, I specified the VM path as provided documentation at openjfx.io. I changed the path under argument to "--module-path "C:\Java\javafx-sdk-19\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml" I still got the error JavaFX not running error Module javafx.controls not found. But I figured out the problem was I did not specify the path in the Preference under JavaFX / JavaFX11+SDK  to  C:\Java\javafx-sdk-19\lib

[in Eclipse Go To windows/preference/JavaFx/JavaFX11+SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSl3n.png)