# JavaFX missing "eu.hansolo" module

Tags: javafx

I'm using for the first time JavaFX on Intellij for an university project that requires me to develop a certain program.

I downloaded the 19.0.2.1 version of JavaFX.

Then, i created a new project, and tried to run the HelloApplication file (the one it automatically creates), and it did not build. So, i started following around 10 different guides, so the steps i did were:

- In 'Project structure', i created a new path to my lib file in the javafxjdk i download before.
- In 'Edit run configurations', i added this code to the option 'add VM options':

```
--module-path /Users/User/Download/javafx-sdk-19.0.2.1/lib
--add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

- I also changed the JAVA_HOME variable (i'm on Mac) using this command:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

But whenever i run, it gives me this error:

```
Executing pre-compile tasks...
Running 'before' tasks
Checking sources
Copying resources... [TenthTry]
Parsing java… [TenthTry]
java: module not found: eu.hansolo.fx.countries
java: module not found: eu.hansolo.fx.heatmap
java: module not found: eu.hansolo.toolboxfx
java: module not found: eu.hansolo.toolbox
```

I have absolutely no clue how i can resolve this. Any help?

Comment: Assuming you are using the modules listed in the error log in your code somewhere, the `--module-path` option needs to include the path to them. It's almost certainly better to use a dependency management tool such as Maven, and follow the instructions at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: I didn't use those modules. I did nothing more than create a new project, set everything up following the same guide you provided, building and running the 'hello world' file that intellij creates automatically, and this was the error log. Also, i followed the guide, but for JavaFX. If you say that Maven is better, i'll use that (although i dont really know what's the difference but i'll google it)

Comment: If you did nothing more than create a new JavaFX project in Idea, then the project would not need the hansolo modules. So you did something else.  Use the [idea new project wizard as documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74764217/error-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing-with-intellij-idea-maven-and-jdk/74764297#74764297).  Just use the defaults in the wizard, don’t add any unnecessary libraries.  The wizard will create a working modular JavaFX project using Maven as the build tool.  You should not download the JavaFX SDK (delete it) or set any VM options for the module path.

Comment: I have the same problem. I installed IDEA, added TornadoFX plugin, created a new project with JavaFX Wizard, compiled and run. Got the messages 

> Task :compileKotlin
e: Module eu.hansolo.toolbox cannot be found in the module graph
e: Module eu.hansolo.toolboxfx cannot be found in the module graph
e: Module eu.hansolo.fx.heatmap cannot be found in the module graph
e: Module eu.hansolo.fx.countries cannot be found in the module graph

Answer (score 9):

I fixed it!

Go to file->project structure->modules and in your modules find those four modules that are throwing an error. change them from "Runtime" to "Compile".

Answer (score 6):

My `module-info` had:

```
requires eu.hansolo.tilesfx;
```

I removed it and was able to compile and run the app from the JavaFX9 book.

Comment: Thank you, if you know anymore info on this, can you please explain?

Comment: No more info that I can add.  It was a sample / demo app in a JavaFX9 book, I can't remember the exact book or example.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Add this dependency in your pom.xml after this dependency it works fine problem is dependency is runtime to convert compile time.

```
'''

  <dependency>
    <groupId>eu.hansolo.fx</groupId>
    <artifactId>countries</artifactId>
    <version>17.0.37</version>
  </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/eu.hansolo/toolboxfx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eu.hansolo</groupId>
        <artifactId>toolboxfx</artifactId>
        <version>17.0.47</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/eu.hansolo/toolbox -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eu.hansolo</groupId>
        <artifactId>toolbox</artifactId>
        <version>17.0.57</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-swing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>21-ea+31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eu.hansolo</groupId>
        <artifactId>medusa</artifactId>
        <version>16.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

'''
```